# Is there a way to play all videos from a channel's uploads sorted by popularity?

Tags: youtube

I'd be okay if they were added to a playlist as well.

Comment: Sorted in order of popularity, I am not sure. But to watch them in published order - [http://darkknight.in/youtube][1]
[1]: http://darkknight.in/youtube

Comment: Like this? https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9mPk8yIk1AUC8PDsUYFBaA/videos?flow=grid&sort=p&view=0

Answer (score 5):

It's different for different types of links.

Adding `?sort=p` to the end of the link for a user's videos to sort by views:

```
https://www.youtube.com/user/USERNAMEHERE/videos?sort=p
```

To sort by most recent, use `sort=dd`, or the reverse `sort=da`.

For sorting results of a search, use `?search_sort=video_view_count`:

```
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_sort=video_view_count&search_query=SEARCH_TERM_HERE
```

or by rating: `search_sort=video_avg_rating`
or by upload date: `search_sort=video_date_uploaded`

To limit search results to videos, add `filters=video`:

```
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_sort=video_view_count&filters=video&search_query=SEARCH_TERM_HERE
```

You can also limit search results by
channels: `filter=channel`
playlists: `filter=playlist`

Having said all that, it appears the features seem to come and go.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out, I'll go step by step and won't use any flashy thing from this website because I made the account just to leave this message.

1. Open any video from the channel you want to create a playlist sorted by popular.
2. Middle click (or right click and open in a new tab) in that user's channel name under the video.
3. Copy everything after **[www.youtube.com/channel/UC](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC)** from the new tab and go to the video again. (I made you go back to the main page of his channel because that page can have this structure too --> /user/"name of the channel"/featured and we don't want that).
4. After the url of the video you are playing add **&list=PU** and then paste the thing you have in your clipboard

The resulting link will have this structure [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="particular](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%22particular) url of the video"**&list=PU**"channel's particular url without the UC"

Comment: works like a charm. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of a YouTube video link on the channel:

```
&feature=mfu_in_order&list=UL
```

Comment: Doesn't work. going to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nh_0cRYebYU&feature=mfu_in_order&list=UL doesn't show ordered list by most popular, and clicking on Next, it doesn't jump to the next popular one (1. 44k views, 2. 17 views).